# Is there a game of perfect information that only has a mixed strategy equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

It is known that certain [simultaneous games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_game), say, [matching pennies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pennies) with no pure strategy equilibrium,  have a mixed strategy equilibrium.

Is simulaneous move at some stage a necessary ingredient of games that don't have a pure strategy equilibirium but have a mixed strategy equilibrium?

It seems to me by induction, if a (finite or infinite)[game of perfect information](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~ted/210F10/References/GameTheory/Chapter3copy.pdf)(with complete information) have a equilibrium, then it must have a pure strategy.

What about (finite or infinite) games of perfect information but incomplete information?

Comment: What is a game of complete information? How is that different from perfect information?

Comment: Complete information means the payoffs given actions are common knowledge. Perfect information means that the past actions of all the players are known.  Now, the usual modelling of complete information is to make Nature a player that gives out types to players so in that terminology every game of incomplete information is also a game of imperfect information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the game is finite or infinite and whether information is complete or not, any game of perfect information that has an equilibrium has an equilibrium in pure strategies.

Given any equilibrium strategy profile, consider some strategy profile where at each node where the player randomizes, he instead plays one of the actions in the support of his strategy.  This will also be an equilibrium since he was indifferent between the payoff from that particular action and the mixed strategy at that node *and* (this is the key part), the randomization does not change any other players' information set.

The reason why it is possible for a game of imperfect information to have only a mixed strategy equilibrium is that randomization not only affects the payoffs given the strategy of the other players but also the information sets of the other players.  When it does not have the latter effect, any mixed strategy can be replaced with pure strategies in its support.

Comment: I have some doubt on your first sentence. Because in a repeated zero-sum game of incomplete information, it is possible that the equilibrium can only be achieved when the informed player uses a partial revealing strategy, i.e. randomizing. See Repeated games with incomplete information(1995) by Aumann and Maschler.

Comment: That's a good observation, but games studied by Aumann & Maschler are not games of perfect information.  The informed and the uninformed player repeatedly play a simultaneous move game (whose payoffs are only known by the informed player), so this does not constitute a counter-example.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. Yet another question: By "change a player's information set", you mean change a player's belief on the information set", right?

Comment: By "information set" we typically mean what the player observes, not what his beliefs are.  For example, suppose player 1 can take one of 3 actions, L, M, or R.  If he does L, player 2 knows he did L.  If he does M or R, player 2 just knows he did M or R (without knowing which one.)  In that case, the two information sets that players 2 might have are {L} or {M,R}.  There is a separate question of player 2's beliefs might be (about how likely M vs. R is) when his information set is {M,R}.